# Is it ok to use identical tables?

Tags: database, performance, database-design

Were currently designing a mobile app being mobile this means that the application will have to store its own data while not online and is connected to SAP. So the management suggests that the major tables be duplicated but with different table name of course. So the app first pulls data on tables designated as APP tables, then when the app is done it pushes data to the identical table designated as SAP tables. Then a custom program will check the SAP tables compare it with the APP tables then update as necessary. Is this ok ? Are there any drawbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all database systems provide [replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_%28computing%29#Database_replication) mechanisms out of the box. Or you can use [existing replication tools](http://www.symmetricds.org/). Developing a reliable, error-free solution on your own will likely turn out to be the more expensive option.